# Java Classpath Issue?

Tags: windows-7, installation, java, eclipse

I am having an issue getting Eclipse running on my machine (Windows 7, 64 bit).

I have the latest version of Java, and can run it from command prompt when I manually navigate to the correct directory and run the file.

However, it appears my class path is not set correctly, since when I attempt to launch eclipse it cannot find the Java resources to run.

I am a bit at a loss since I thought I had set my class path correctly, so that Eclipse would find it, could anyone give me walk through on how to correctly set my classpath.

Comment: hmm, if classpath isn't set then classpath=. (and that means it'll be the directory that the .class file is in) so you should still be able to run simple things. maybe the issue is the path to java.exe not the classpath.

Comment: Ah, I think that is it then. I thought the path to Java.exe was the classpath? or where is that value set?

Comment: well, in windows the PATH variable is set where they're all set. ctrl panel.. system. (and err then) .advanced..environment variables. you can edit the path variable and stick a semi-colon on and add the directory java.exe and javac.exe are. Will Eclipse be happy yet is another matter

Comment: Ah! You set me in motion toward finding out the issue. Apparently it was that my path was no longer correct, and additionally I had a mis match between 64bit and 32bit between Java and Eclipse. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With barlops help I figured this out!

My issue was actually a `Path` issue rather than `Classpath` issue.

My path was not correctly set, but barlops advice about setting it to the directory of java.exe and javac.exe allowed me to at least run "java" from the command line without having to navigate to the directory manually.

From there I still had an issue with eclipse, where it failed to load a resource: "...jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"

Googling around that issue it looked to be related to having a 64 bit version of Eclipse when running a 32 bit version of Java. I switched over to a 32 bit version of Eclipse now and it works.